# Jekyll dynamic collection list

Tags: dynamic, widget, jekyll, liquid

I am trying to create a widget which lists the posts defined as custom collections in Jekyll. the widget is something similar:

```
<!--start WIDGET card-->
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title h5 ">{{ widget.title }}</h3>
        {% capture collName %} site.{{ widget.name }} {% endcapture %}
        {% assign collection = collName %}
        {{ collection }} <!-- IT PRINTS CORRECT site.posts1 -->
            {% for post in collection %}
                <li>{{ post.title }} {{ post.page.title }}</li>

            {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
<!--end card-->
```

This way I cannot access the posts, despite the fact that `collName` and `collection` are printed out well, why if I hardcode this way, there is no problem:

```
<!-- 
{% for post in site.posts1 %}<li>{{ post.title }} {{ post.page.title }}</li>{% endfor %} 
THIS PRINTS CORRECT 
-->
```

In my `_config.yml` I have:

```
collections:
  posts1:
    output: true
```

What do you think I am getting wrong in order to have a widget that dynamically prints out a list of posts in the defined collection?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that variables created using `capture` are stored as strings. So in `{% for post in collection %}` you are trying to iterate over a string and not the `site.posts1` array.

What you could do instead is:

```
{% assign collection = site.collections | where: "label", widget.name %}
{% for post in collection  %}
  <li>{{ post.title }} {{ post.page.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```